# an embarrassment of possibilities

Tags: phrase-meaning

> In addition to the question of dimensions, string theory suffered from another awkward issue: There appeared to be at least five different theories and millions of ways the extra dimensions could be curled up, which was quite **an embarrassment of possibilities** for those advocating that string theory was the unique theory of everything.

Source: The Grand Design by Stephen Hawking

I don't understand the phrase "an embarrassment of possibilities". It seems to me that "an embarrassment" is sufficient since it is an embarrassment for the advocates. What does the phrase actually mean?

Comment: [embarrassment](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/embarrassment) - an over abundance.

Comment: Expressions of this kind are variants of the idiom [an embarrassment of riches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassment_of_riches) - when you have so much of a good thing that it starts to be problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "an embarrassment of X" means that you have too much of X, or more of X than you need. It is most commonly used with the word "riches", that is, "an embarrassment of riches", meaning a lot of money. It is not the common meaning of the word "embarrassment", meaning "the act of feeling self-conscious or guilty". Maybe there's some connection, like if you have way more of something than you need you might feel guilty about it, but that's not the literal meaning.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the expression originated with a French play. I would guess that the characters in the play found that suddenly becoming rich caused them more problems than it solved.

Answer (score 3):

In the quoted text, *an embarrassment of possibilities* means *an embarrassingly large number of possibilities* because of the idiom *an embarrassment of riches*, which Kate Bunting and Jay have already pointed out.